# Rss Feed Facebook change language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

I neeed change language in my Rss 2.0 Feed Facebook for other language. Any solutiobns or link to API?

Section:

```
<language>en-us</language>
```

Example:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=50063176484&format=rss20

Comment: What do you even mean by that? That page’s feed seems to consist mainly of posts in Polish(?) language – so what else do you expect the RSS feed to deliver?

Comment: Facebook set language en-us instead Polish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=50063176484&format=rss20&locale=en_US
```

Locales list you can find [here](https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)